# Set font in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-typeface

I want to set font inside SimpleCustorAdpater. I have implemented SimpleCustorAdpater usng this code:

```
    if(cur!=null&&cur.getCount() > 0)
    {
    do
     {
        String[] fromColumns = { "A_name", "T_name","D_name" };
        int[] toViews = { R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(activity,R.layout.query_cell_schedules, cur, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        QueryFragment.listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
      while(cur.moveToNext());
    }
```

For that I have to  overwrite the SimpleCursorAdapter's [ViewBinding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) something like this

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binding=adapter.setViewBinder( new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder()
{
boolean SetViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
{
  TextView tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  TextView tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  TextView tv3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

  //Setting typeface  here

  return true;
}
});
```

But it is giving me error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`

How can I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [setViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder)) return `void` and you are trying to set that to a variable. The correct way of doing this is:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binding = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    boolean SetViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
      TextView tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      TextView tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      TextView tv3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

      //Setting typeface  here

      return true;
    }
});

adapter.setViewBinder(binding);
```

Comment: Where do I have to putt his code wrt my code, should I put it in  do while loop?

Comment: @VivekWarde You must have it where you had the snippet you posted. It's exactly the same code just reordered so you grab a reference to the created VuewBinder.